# Suggestion regarding Notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, calendar

I have an app in which I have to perform a crud of the alerts. I am confused about which pattern I follow. Meaning whether use the flutter_local_notification schedule for alerts or https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar package for flutter. I want the notification to schedule like daily, monthly, weekly. also can turn off all the alerts. Also want the notification to sync with android and ios platform. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) 's [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin-class.html) class caters for Android & iOS platform. You can read further in their docs. It has zonedSchedule method for daily/monthly/weekly & also cancelAll method for turning off notification.

Comment: how can we turn it all notification on because I cannot recall this method? In the documentation @Phil D

Comment: Let's say you run the method zonedSchedule & set like certain seconds, it will then show it up. I think you can check out this video, it explains clearly about using the local notification package & also some scheduling in it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRy5dmts3X8

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I can make the schedule notification as described in the documentation. but my issue is how can I turn on all notifications when I cancel all.

Comment: You could just schedule it back.